# Visual Studio Code Crash Loop

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I cannot open my Visual Studio Code, it always crashes when I open it.  It only show this message :

[image: My VS Code on Start Up]

when I clicked reopen, it show that message again repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try terminating any exe in your task manager by the name of code.exe. I experienced the same issue few days ago

Answer (score 0):

If terminating as suggested by LearningPhase doesn't work, you could re-install.